# Python open multiple cmd prompts for udp

Tags: python, subprocess, udp, command

I am trying to run a python script that opens up 2 command prompts simulating the client and the server for udp.  Basically, I want something like this

```
os.system('cmd /k "python server.py"')

os.system('cmd /k "python client.py"')
```

I can run the scripts individually to get it working, but I want a single script to execute the entire thing.

Comment: Using a thread should work, as an answer suggests, but why are you running a python script from python by running `os.system`, which runs `cmd`, which runs `python`, which runs `server.py`. Couldn't you just implement a `def run()` in `server.py` and then call `server.run()`?

Comment: I've never done that, but I want both running.  Let's say server.run() calls an infinite while loop, it would never call client.py, right?

Comment: Yes, so you still need to create threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use threading in the following way:

```
import threading
import os

def server():
    os.system("python server.py")

def client():
    os.system("python client.py")

def main():
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server)
    server_thread.start()
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client)
    client_thread.start()
```